# Network Error while trying to connect aws ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have hosted a dotNet core web API APP on AWS EC2 Linux.I have hosted the APP as a service and it's running since last 3 days.

[image]

I tried to call a API using postman (http://3.23.63.255:5000/Test/GetAll) but i am getting following error message.

```
Could Not get any Response
```

In inbound and outbound rules i have allowed all ports and Protocol.

Security Groups :-
[image]

Comment: If you login into the instance, does it work when you `curl` from localhost? Also can you show your security groups?

Comment: yes it's working on local host (aws ec2).

Comment: @Marcin i have added only one security group.i have updated in question.

Comment: So is it in a Public Subnet? ie does the subnet have a Route Table with a 0.0.0.0/0 entry that maps to an Internet Gateway (IGW)? ps this is an AWS SysOps Exam Answer...

Comment: @JeremyThompson yes.

Comment: Ok, tricky one, do you have a NACL rule denying traffic? If you spin up a Windows machine in the same VPC can you access the website with the private IP address? Silly question, but that is the correct URL yeah? What's the URL running locally?

Answer (score 0):

It seems your machine is in a standard Amazon VPC. This might be the problem.
The VPC will translate to the appropriate private IP automatically from Amazon's docs.

Add the `rule` to security group, open firewall on server for `port` 5000.

When finish the setting, relaunch your machine.

[The accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37076192/webmin-on-aws-ec2-port-10000-doesnt-work) from Mark B.

> You have to have a security group assigned to the instance, and open
> port 10000 in the security group. You should be able to change/add a
> security group if your instance is in an VPC. If it is in EC2 classic
> you will have to launch a new instance.